# how to groupby and take mean of value by symetrically looping forward and backward on the date value in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I need to group data on ID and then replace the missing value of price by iterating on a date value up and down. first, look for 1 date value up and down if no data go 2 date values up and down until there is a mean value for all rows.

[image: Data Format]

- Input data :

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555,555),
                  Date = c("1-Jun", "18-Jun", "3-Jul", "4-Jul", "25-Jul", "3-Nov", "7-Nov", "28_Nov",
                           "1-Jun", "18-Jun", "3-Jul", "4-Jul", "25-Jul", "3-Nov", "7-Nov", "28_Nov",
                           "30-Nov"),
                  price = c(NA, NA, 100, NA, 25, NA, 50, NA, 400, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 200)
                  )
```

Updated requirement:

- Input data :

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11),
                  Date = c("1-Jun", "5-Jun", "8-Jun", "9-Jun", "14-Jun", "16-Jun", "20-Jun", "21-Jun"),
                  price = c(NA, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, NA)
)
```

I need to impute all missing dates between the available dates for each id's and then go symmetrically up and down to impute missing. Also, not always I need the average between two, eg: when I go 2 dates up and down and I see only 1 value, then I would impute that value.

[image]

Comment: Please share your data in a reproducible format, not as an image.

Comment: Hi @Rijin, please find one possible solution to your request in my answer below. If it meets your needs, please consider marking this answer as "validated" and/or "upvoted". Cheers

Comment: @deschen there is an updated request, would like to have your solution as well

Comment: Hi @Rijin. I think you should post another question linking to this one as it is a different question. That would make each answer available to other SO users. Cheers.

Comment: @Rijin, I don't see the difference in the desired result between the two images (i.e. first post and the updated post). Is this normal? In addition, the dates should include the year so that missing dates can be filled in. So, please specify the year in your data.

Comment: @lovalery I have posted a new question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70323453/mean-imputation-by-filling-in-missing-dates-and-by-symetrically-iterating-over-d
I have tried to explain why the extra date insertion is needed

Comment: Hi @Rijin, Thanks for having posted a new question. That said, to keep this one understandable for all SO users, it would be helpful if you could restore the first image of this post because it is not the original image showing the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below with a reprex one possible solution using the `data.table` library.

I built a function to make it easier to use.

**Reprex**

- Code of the `NA_imputations()` function

```r
library(data.table)

NA_imputations <- function(x) {
  
  x[, rows := .I]
  
  z <- x[, .I[!is.na(price)]]
  
  id_1 <- z[-length(z)]
  id_2 <- z[-1]
  
  values <- x[z, .(price = price, id = id)]
  values_1 <- values[-nrow(values)]
  names(values_1) <- c("price_1", "id_o1")
  values_2 <- values[-1]
  names(values_2) <- c("price_2", "id_o2")
  
  subtract <- z[-1] - z[-length(z)]
  
  r <- data.table(id_1, values_1, id_2, values_2, subtract)
  
  Results <- r[, `:=` (id_mean = fifelse(subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0, id_1+(subtract/2), (id_1+id_2)/2),
                       mean = fifelse(subtract >= 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, (price_1+price_2)/2, NA_real_))
               ][, `:=` (price_1 = NULL, id_o1 = NULL, id_2 = NULL, price_2 = NULL, id_o2 = NULL)
                 ][x, on = .(id_mean = rows)
                   ][, price := fcoalesce(price, mean)
                     ][, mean := NULL
                       ][r[subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0,id_1]:r[subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0,id_mean-1], price := lapply(price, nafill, type = "nocb"), by = .(id)
                         ][, price := nafill(price, type = "nocb"), by = .(id)
                           ][, price := nafill(price, type = "locf")
                             ][, `:=` (id_1 = NULL, id_mean = NULL, subtract = NULL)][]
  
  return(Results)
}
```

- Output of the `NA_imputations()` function

```
NA_imputations(df1)
#>        id   Date price
#>     <num> <char> <num>
#>  1:    11  1-Jun 100.0
#>  2:    11 18-Jun 100.0
#>  3:    11  3-Jul 100.0
#>  4:    11  4-Jul  62.5
#>  5:    11 25-Jul  25.0
#>  6:    11  3-Nov  37.5
#>  7:    11  7-Nov  50.0
#>  8:    11 28_Nov  50.0
#>  9:   555  1-Jun 400.0
#> 10:   555 18-Jun 400.0
#> 11:   555  3-Jul 400.0
#> 12:   555  4-Jul 400.0
#> 13:   555 25-Jul 300.0
#> 14:   555  3-Nov 200.0
#> 15:   555  7-Nov 200.0
#> 16:   555 28_Nov 200.0
#> 17:   555 30-Nov 200.0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I have an updated requirement, which is similar. have a look @lovalery

Comment: Hi @Rijin. I think you should post another question linking to this one as it is a different question. That would make each answer available to other SO users. Cheers.