# mean imputation by filling in missing dates and by symetrically iterating over dates up and down to find the closest value available in r

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, missing-data

I need to impute all missing dates between the available dates for each id's and then go symmetrically up and down to impute missing. Also, not always I need the average between two, eg: when I go 2 dates up and down and I see only 1 value, then I would impute that value.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11),
                  Date = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21"),
                  price = c(NA, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, NA)
)
```

There is an excellent solution for missing imputation on a symmetrical iteration by @lovalery
[how to groupby and take mean of value by symetrically looping forward and backward on the date value in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70218460/how-to-groupby-and-take-mean-of-value-by-symetrically-looping-forward-and-backwa)

In the above solution, the date present is used, but this can be an issue when there is a large number of dates missing in between.
Hence I wanted to insert all missing dates in between and then symmetrically move in both directions until I get at least 1 value in either direction, I need to retain it, if 2 values I need the mean.

[image]

Update: we also need to consider cases when the price is only present in the first date or in the last date. Also if same price is present in multiple dates

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
                     12,12,12,
                     13,13,13),
              Date = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21",
                       "2021-07-01","2021-07-03","2021-07-05",
                       "2021-08-01","2021-08-03","2021-08-05"),
              price = c(200, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, NA,
                        10,NA,NA,
                        NA,NA,20)
```

)

I used the function NA_imputations_dates_v2 by @lovalery

```
df1 <- setDT(df1)
df2 <- NA_imputations_dates_v2(df1)
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by = c("id","Date"),all.x = T)
```

Comment: @lovalery there can be cases where the date difference can be large hence instead of checking for available near values, it makes sense to add all the dates and then iterate in both directions so that the imputed value will be close to the nearest date value available. let me know your comments

Comment: Hi @Rijin, thanks for posting a new question. Please find below a possible answer. If it meets your needs, please consider marking this answer as "validated" and/or "upvoted". Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery your solution works perfectly. but as in we work let's try to foresee all possible errors that might occur so that we can propose a scalable solution. 
The solution you provided will throw an error if the price value is present only with the start date or with the end date. I have updated a new data frame code in the question.

Comment: error is as follows:
"Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 41 rows; more than 30 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and data.table issue tracker for advice.

Comment: Called from: vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__, 
    incomparables = c(0L, NA_integer_))) {
    NULL
} else as.double(nrow(x) + nrow(i)))"

Comment: Hi @Rijin, please find below an edit (located at the bottom of my original answer) to take into account the more general case provided by your updated dataset. I hope that this function will meet your needs. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below with a reprex one possible solution using the `data.table` and `padr` libraries.

I built a function to make it easier to use.

**Reprex**

- Your dataset #1

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11),
                  Date = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21"),
                  price = c(NA, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, NA))
```

- Code of the `NA_imputations_dates()` function

```r
library(data.table)
library(padr)

NA_imputations_dates <- function(x) {
  
  setDT(x)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
  
  x <- pad(x, interval = "day", group = "id")
  
  setDT(x)[, rows := .I]
  
  z <- x[, .I[!is.na(price)]]
  
  id_1 <- z[-length(z)]
  id_2 <- z[-1]
  
  values <- x[z, .(price = price, id = id)]
  values_1 <- values[-nrow(values)]
  names(values_1) <- c("price_1", "id_o1")
  values_2 <- values[-1]
  names(values_2) <- c("price_2", "id_o2")
  
  subtract <- z[-1] - z[-length(z)]
  
  r <- data.table(id_1, values_1, id_2, values_2, subtract)
  
  r <- r[, `:=` (id_mean = fifelse(subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0, id_1+(subtract/2), (id_1+id_2)/2),
                 mean = fifelse(subtract >= 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, (price_1+price_2)/2, NA_real_))
         ][, `:=` (price_1 = NULL, id_1 = NULL, id_o1 = NULL, id_2 = NULL, price_2 = NULL, id_o2 = NULL, subtract = NULL)
           ][x, on = .(id_mean = rows)][, dummy := cumsum(!is.na(mean)), by = .(id)]
  
  h <-  r[, .(price = na.omit(price)), by = .(dummy)]
  
  Results <- r[, price := NULL
               ][h, on = .(dummy)
                 ][, price := fifelse(!is.na(mean), mean, price)
                   ][, `:=` (id_mean = NULL, mean = NULL, dummy = NULL)][]
  
  return(Results)
}
```

- Output of the `NA_imputations_dates()` function

```r
NA_imputations_dates(df1)
#>     id       Date price
#>  1: 11 2021-06-01   100
#>  2: 11 2021-06-02   100
#>  3: 11 2021-06-03   100
#>  4: 11 2021-06-04   100
#>  5: 11 2021-06-05   100
#>  6: 11 2021-06-06   100
#>  7: 11 2021-06-07   100
#>  8: 11 2021-06-08   100
#>  9: 11 2021-06-09   100
#> 10: 11 2021-06-10   100
#> 11: 11 2021-06-11    75
#> 12: 11 2021-06-12    50
#> 13: 11 2021-06-13    50
#> 14: 11 2021-06-14    50
#> 15: 11 2021-06-15    50
#> 16: 11 2021-06-16    50
#> 17: 11 2021-06-17   125
#> 18: 11 2021-06-18   200
#> 19: 11 2021-06-19   200
#> 20: 11 2021-06-20   200
#> 21: 11 2021-06-21   200
#>     id       Date price
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### EDIT OF THE FUNCTION TO PROCESS YOUR MORE GENERAL DATASET #2

As a follow-up of your comment, please find below the modified version of the function (i.e. `NA_imputations_dates_v2()`) to deal with the more general case provided by your new dataset (i.e. `dataset #2`).

**Reprex**

- Your dataset #2

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
                         12,12,12,
                         13,13,13),
                  Date = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21",
                           "2021-07-01","2021-07-03","2021-07-05",
                           "2021-08-01","2021-08-03","2021-08-05"),
                  price = c(NA, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, NA,
                            10,NA,NA,
                            NA,NA,20))
```

- Code of the `NA_imputations_dates_v2()` function

```r
library(data.table)
library(padr)  
  
NA_imputations_dates_v2 <- function(x) {
  
  setDT(x)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
  
  x <- pad(x, interval = "day", group = "id")

  setDT(x)[, rows := .I]
  
  z <- x[, .I[!is.na(price)]]
  
  id_1 <- z[-length(z)]
  id_2 <- z[-1]
  
  values <- x[z, .(price = price, id = id)]
  values_1 <- values[-nrow(values)]
  names(values_1) <- c("price_1", "id_o1")
  values_2 <- values[-1]
  names(values_2) <- c("price_2", "id_o2")
  
  subtract <- z[-1] - z[-length(z)]
  
  r <- data.table(id_1, values_1, id_2, values_2, subtract)

  r <- r[, `:=` (id_mean = fifelse(subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, id_1+(subtract/2), NA_real_),
                 mean = fifelse(subtract >= 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, (price_1+price_2)/2, NA_real_))
         ][, `:=` (price_1 = NULL, id_1 = NULL, id_o1 = NULL, id_2 = NULL, price_2 = NULL, id_o2 = NULL, subtract = NULL)
           ][x, on = .(id_mean = rows)][, dummy := cumsum(!is.na(mean)), by = .(id)]
  
  h <-  r[, .(price = na.omit(price)), by = .(dummy, id)]
  
  Results <- r[, price := NULL
               ][h, on = .(dummy, id)
                 ][, price := fifelse(!is.na(mean), mean, price)
                   ][, `:=` (id_mean = NULL, mean = NULL, dummy = NULL)][]
  
  return(Results)
}
```

- Output of the `NA_imputations_dates_v2()` function

```r
NA_imputations_dates_v2(df1)
#>     id       Date price
#>  1: 11 2021-06-01   100
#>  2: 11 2021-06-02   100
#>  3: 11 2021-06-03   100
#>  4: 11 2021-06-04   100
#>  5: 11 2021-06-05   100
#>  6: 11 2021-06-06   100
#>  7: 11 2021-06-07   100
#>  8: 11 2021-06-08   100
#>  9: 11 2021-06-09   100
#> 10: 11 2021-06-10   100
#> 11: 11 2021-06-11    75
#> 12: 11 2021-06-12    50
#> 13: 11 2021-06-13    50
#> 14: 11 2021-06-14    50
#> 15: 11 2021-06-15    50
#> 16: 11 2021-06-16    50
#> 17: 11 2021-06-17   125
#> 18: 11 2021-06-18   200
#> 19: 11 2021-06-19   200
#> 20: 11 2021-06-20   200
#> 21: 11 2021-06-21   200
#> 22: 12 2021-07-01    10
#> 23: 12 2021-07-02    10
#> 24: 12 2021-07-03    10
#> 25: 12 2021-07-04    10
#> 26: 12 2021-07-05    10
#> 27: 13 2021-08-01    20
#> 28: 13 2021-08-02    20
#> 29: 13 2021-08-03    20
#> 30: 13 2021-08-04    20
#> 31: 13 2021-08-05    20
#>     id       Date price
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

### SECOND EDIT OF THE FUNCTION TO PROCESS YOUR MORE GENERAL DATASET #3

As a follow-up of your second comment, please find below the modified version of the function (i.e. `NA_imputations_dates_v3()`) to deal with the more general case provided by your new dataset (i.e. `dataset #3`).

**Reprex**

- Your dataset #3

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
                         12,12,12,
                         13,13,13),
                  Date = c("2021-06-01", "2021-06-05", "2021-06-08", "2021-06-09", "2021-06-14", "2021-06-16", "2021-06-20", "2021-06-21",
                           "2021-07-01","2021-07-03","2021-07-05",
                           "2021-08-01","2021-08-03","2021-08-05"),
                  price = c(NA, NA,100, NA, 50, NA, 200, 200,
                            10,NA,NA,
                            NA,NA,20))
```

- Code of the `NA_imputations_dates_v3()` function

```r
library(data.table)
library(padr)  
  
NA_imputations_dates_v3 <- function(x) {
  
  setDT(x)[, Date := as.Date(Date)]
  
  x <- pad(x, interval = "day", group = "id")
  
  setDT(x)[, rows := .I]
  
  z <- x[, .I[!is.na(price)]]
  
  id_1 <- z[-length(z)]
  id_2 <- z[-1]
  
  values <- x[z, .(price = price, id = id)]
  values_1 <- values[-nrow(values)]
  names(values_1) <- c("price_1", "id_o1")
  values_2 <- values[-1]
  names(values_2) <- c("price_2", "id_o2")
  
  subtract <- z[-1] - z[-length(z)]
  
  r <- data.table(id_1, values_1, id_2, values_2, subtract)
  
  r <- r[, `:=` (id_mean = fifelse(subtract > 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, id_1+(subtract/2), NA_real_),
                 mean = fifelse(subtract >= 2 & subtract %% 2 == 0 & id_o1 == id_o2, (price_1+price_2)/2, NA_real_))
         ][, `:=` (price_1 = NULL, id_1 = NULL, id_o1 = NULL, id_2 = NULL, price_2 = NULL, id_o2 = NULL, subtract = NULL)
           ][x, on = .(id_mean = rows)][, dummy := cumsum(!is.na(mean)), by = .(id)]
  
  r <- r[, price_lag := shift(price, 1), by = .(dummy, id)]
  
  h <-  r[, .(price = na.omit(price)), by = .(dummy, id, price_lag)]
  
  h <- h[h[,.I[is.na(price_lag)]]][, price_lag := NULL]
  
  Results <- r[, `:=` (price = NULL, price_lag = NULL)
               ][h, on = .(dummy, id)
                 ][, price := fifelse(!is.na(mean), mean, price)
                   ][, `:=` (id_mean = NULL, mean = NULL, dummy = NULL)][]
  
  return(Results)
}
```

- Output of the `NA_imputations_dates_v3()` function

```r
NA_imputations_dates_v3(df1)  
#>     id       Date price
#>  1: 11 2021-06-01   100
#>  2: 11 2021-06-02   100
#>  3: 11 2021-06-03   100
#>  4: 11 2021-06-04   100
#>  5: 11 2021-06-05   100
#>  6: 11 2021-06-06   100
#>  7: 11 2021-06-07   100
#>  8: 11 2021-06-08   100
#>  9: 11 2021-06-09   100
#> 10: 11 2021-06-10   100
#> 11: 11 2021-06-11    75
#> 12: 11 2021-06-12    50
#> 13: 11 2021-06-13    50
#> 14: 11 2021-06-14    50
#> 15: 11 2021-06-15    50
#> 16: 11 2021-06-16    50
#> 17: 11 2021-06-17   125
#> 18: 11 2021-06-18   200
#> 19: 11 2021-06-19   200
#> 20: 11 2021-06-20   200
#> 21: 11 2021-06-21   200
#> 22: 12 2021-07-01    10
#> 23: 12 2021-07-02    10
#> 24: 12 2021-07-03    10
#> 25: 12 2021-07-04    10
#> 26: 12 2021-07-05    10
#> 27: 13 2021-08-01    20
#> 28: 13 2021-08-02    20
#> 29: 13 2021-08-03    20
#> 30: 13 2021-08-04    20
#> 31: 13 2021-08-05    20
#>     id       Date price
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: thank you for your solution. I just encountered another data scenario where the same price can be repeated for an id at multiple dates. In the modified data frame code I added price 200 twice for the id 11. now if you can run the code for df2 and df3, on df3 you will see that there are multiple values for same date

Comment: Hi @Rijin, (i) please find a second edit (located at the bottom of my original answer and first edit) to take into account the more general case provided by your newly updated dataset (i.e. dataset #3). I hope that this function will meet your needs (...and hope that it is the last adaptation you need ;-) ); (ii) you don't need to use `allow.cartesian = TRUE` I think your problem is that you generated the dataset via a `merge`: if you use the datasets `dataset #2` and `dataset #3` that I included in my successive edits, everything works fine. Cheers.

Comment: sorry for the repeated edits, I should have thought of all possible errors. I do have more complex data, but I am using all these df as a sample one so that it's easy.
one last thing the code you have used for `dataset 3` is not the same as the one I have posted. I kept value 200 at 1 and 7th position wherein you kept 200 twice at the end

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood the structure of your `dataset #3`. That said, this is not clear to me. How would you like to impute the `NA` values between the 1st `200` and the next value (i.e. `100`): these two values are separated by 6 NAs... Should an average be computed in this case and, if so, to which row(s) should this average be imputed? Or should the NAs be filled with 3 values `200` and 3 values `100`?

Comment: I will explain.  Dates `2021-06-01, 2021-06-05 and 2021-06-08` with price values as follows ` 200, NA, 100`. First, we impute the missing dates in between the existing date and then try to get an average value for the date `2021-06-05` which has a missing price. for this on groupby 'id' we go dates symmetrically up and down till we find a value to take the average. In our case when we go 3 iterations up and down we get the value `100 at date 2021-06-08` and no value for 2021-06-02, hence we need to retain 100.

Comment: If there was a value at date 2021-06-02 we would have taken an average with 100. Hope this is clear and the functions you have written is perfectly doing this job. but the function throws duplicate in cases where a product has same price at different dates.
I you can use the `df1 creation code` along with `df1 <- setDT(df1);
df2 <- NA_imputations_dates_v2(df1);
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by = c("id","Date"),all.x = T)` you can see the duplicates in df3. `df1 had 14 rows but df3 will have 18 rows`

Comment: Hi @Rijin Thanks for the clarification. Concerning your last request, I don't have the solution for the moment... and I don't know if I will have it! This is getting extremely complicated... To build the first function I have retained an approach adapted to your first question. I managed to adapt it to your second question, then to two new complications of the dataset. But this third request is particularly difficult to take into account with the approach I chose initially... I'll keep thinking about it, but I'm afraid I won't be able to find a solution...

Comment: That said, I think you should (i) think carefully about all the possible cases you are likely to get, (ii) build a dataset with all these cases, (iii) post a new question with this new complete dataset. This would have a 2 benefits: (i) other SO users could also work on this new dataset presenting exhaustively all the cases, which would increase your chances to get the best possible answer in a reasonable time; (ii) having the whole set of cases at the beginning may allow to find a better approach to avoid having to adapt a function n times and to find a dead end at the umpteenth adaptation